# How can I deploy a dockerized Node app to a DigitalOcean server using Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, bitbucket-pipelines

I've got a NodeJS project in a Bitbucket repo, and I am struggling to understand how to use Bitbucket Pipelines to get it from there onto my DigitalOcean server, where it can be served on the web.

So far I've got this

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm run build
```

So now the app was built and should be saved as a single file `server.js` in a theoretical `/dist` directory.

**How now do I dockerize this file and then upload it to my DigitalOcean?
I can't find any examples for something like this.**

I did find a Docker template in the Bitbucket Pipelines editor, but it only somewhat describes creating a Docker image, and not at all how to actually deploy it to a DigitalOcean server (or anywhere)

```
  - step:
      name: Build and Test
      script:
        - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
        - docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}
        - docker save ${IMAGE_NAME} --output "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
      services:
        - docker
      caches:
        - docker
      artifacts:
        - "*.tar"
  - step:
      name: Deploy to Production
      deployment: Production
      script:
        - echo ${DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD} | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
        - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
        - docker load --input "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
        - VERSION="prod-0.1.${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
        - IMAGE=${DOCKERHUB_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}
        - docker tag "${IMAGE_NAME}" "${IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
        - docker push "${IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
      services:
        - docker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to SSH into your DigitalOcean VPS and then do some steps there:

- Pull the current code
- Build the docker file
- Deploy the docker file

An example could look like this:

Create some script like "deployment.sh" in your repository root:

```sh
cd <path_to_local_repo>
git pull origin master
docker container stop <container_name>
docker container rm <container_name>
docker image build -t <image_name> .
docker container run -itd --name <container_name> <image_name>
```

and then add the following into your pipeline:

```yaml
# ...
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - cat ./deployment.sh | ssh <ssh_user>@<ssh_host>
```

You have to add your ssh key for your repository on your server, though. Check out the following link, on how to do this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITTEMP/Use+SSH+keys+in+Bitbucket+Pipelines

Here is a similar question, but using PHP: [Using BitBucket Pipelines to Deploy onto VPS via SSH Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053687/using-bitbucket-pipelines-to-deploy-onto-vps-via-ssh-access)

Comment: `You have to add your ssh key for your repository on your server,` Maurice, is there any way to accomplish this without putting the ssh key on the server?

Comment: Maybe there is, but why would you not want to put an ssh key on your server? That's how you connect to servers... @CodyBugstein

Comment: Maurice, do you know how I can pass variables to `./deployment.sh` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate @CodyBugstein?

Comment: i.e. I want the script to know what branch we're in

Comment: According to [this doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/), you can use `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` in your script to pass it - so you will have to write `- cat ./deployment.sh $BITBUCKET_BRANCH | ssh <ssh_user>@<ssh_host>`. Then in your bash script you can reference this variable with `$1` @CodyBugstein